# Converting ratio to floating points

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of data in the form of "x : y", and I am trying to convert it to the floating point number x/y. Below is my code

```
def ratio_to_float (ratio):
    [numer,denum] = ratio.split(" : ")
    if int(denum) == 0:
        num = math.inf
    else:
        num = int(numer)/int(denum)
    return num
```

However, I keep getting the error below

> ```
> [numer,denum] = ratio.split(" : ")
> ```
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

However, the last time I check, the list are still of the form "x : y". Can someone please tell me which part of my code is causing this error? Any help is appreciated. (:

---

Edit: I actually have a Series type object from pandas library that contains strings of these ratios. My input is lst.map(ratio_to_float, na_action = "ignore").

I also tried it on the first 5 entries, and they seem to work well.

Comment: right before that line do `print(ratio.split(" : "))` to see what it actually is.

Comment: Even when you get past the split problem, you don't want to do `num = int(numer)/int(denum)`, because that is going to force integer division, instead of giving you a floating point answer.  You want `float(numer)/float(denum)`

Comment: @gariepy: The question's tagged Python-3.x so integer division is not an issue when using the `/` operator.

Comment: @gariepy if the OP has tagged correctly for Python 3.x - even `int(number) / int(denum)` will result in a float result...

Comment: Good point, my bad :)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It just prints ['x', 'y']

Comment: @GuoXianYau: Are you getting the actual strings `'x'` and `'y'` or is that just shorthand for some numbers? I'd expect that to cause a whole different set of exceptions, but not the one you describe.

Comment: @Blckknght It's short hand. Like, the relationship is x+y=100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with a `pandas` series, then here's my take on it. You can use the builtin `fractions.Fraction` class and a bit of string manipulation to do the lifting...

```
import pandas as pd
from fractions import Fraction

s = pd.Series(["37 : 63", "100 : 0", "45 : 55"])

def ratio_to_float(value):
    # Change : to / and remove spaces...
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        return value
    s = value.translate(str.maketrans(':', '/', ' '))
    try:
        # Let's see if the Fraction class can handle it
        return float(Fraction(s))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return pd.np.nan # or whatever...
```

Then using:

```
s.map(ratio_to_float)
```

Gives you:

```
0    0.587302
1         NaN
2    0.818182
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This raise another error though, it says "AttributeError: "float" object has no attribute 'translate'". Pretty sure value is not of type float though.

Comment: I'll double check. I am really confused by it now.

Comment: @GuoXianYau I've updated the code to return the original value if it isn't a string... can't do much else without proper input/output - but given what you've provided - it should work - can't spend much longer trying to help though

Comment: Thank you. Your code helped a lot. And I am starting to think my roommates are actually pranking me by changing one of the input to "33:67", i.e. without the spaces.

Comment: I'm giving you the point because your comment helps me the most to debug it. (:

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting says that `split` is only returning a one-value list at some point. That means that somewhere while your program is running it is calling your function with a string that does not contain `" : "` in it. If you're operating on a list of ratios, perhaps one is malformed (missing a space, perhaps). Or if you're reading from a file, perhaps the last line is an empty string?

To troubleshoot the issue, you might try putting in a `try`/`except` block around the `split` and unpacking, and printing some diagnostic information when the exception happens:

```
def ratio_to_float (ratio):
    try:
        numer, denum = ratio.split(" : ")
    except ValueError:
        print(repr(ratio))
        raise
    if int(denum) == 0:
        num = math.inf
    else:
        num = int(numer)/int(denum)
    return num
```

Comment: Somehow it does not print any information. The only error are the ones I pasted above. :|

Comment: Look just before the exception traceback appears. There should be an extra output line, with the `ratio` argument printed. It might just be `''` if the `ratio` string was empty.

Comment: think it actually might be '' :\

Answer (score 0):

`.split(":")` remove spaces.

Code:

```
def ratio_to_float(ratio):
    numer,denum = ratio.split(":")
    if int(denum) == 0:
        num = math.inf
        print(num)
    else:
        num = int(numer)/int(denum)
        print(num)
    return num

ratio_to_float("10:5")
```

Output: `2`

---

If you are reading a list of ratios:

```
def ratio_to_float(ratio):
    res=[]
    for r in ratio:
        [numer,denum] = r.split(":")
        numer=int(numer)
        denum=int(denum)
        if denum == 0:
            num = math.inf
        else:
            num = (numer)/(denum)
        res.append(num)
    return res

print(ratio_to_float(["10:5", "5:2"]))
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 2.5]
```

Comment: Why does the '[' and ']' matters though?

Comment: That won't help. Brackets in that position are not necessary, but also not harmful.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this helps - if the OP is suffering from too few (as it seems) (or possibly too many) when unpacking the `ratio` - there's little difference - the input just needs a bit of sanitising...

Comment: @Blckknght Its actually a `split()` issue. `:` doesn't have spaces trailing I guess..

Comment: @GuoXianYau not `[` `]` remove spaces within brackets in split()

Comment: @GuoXianYau I hope you found your issue, also use float instead of int.

Comment: @AniMenon: That sounds a whole lot like a guess to me.

Comment: @AniMenon It didn't help. The issue is still there.

Comment: @Blckknght Well your answer is the same.

Comment: @GuoXianYau What is the error you get? And what is the input you are giving?

Comment: @AniMenon I have a list lst = ["37 : 63", "100 : 0", "45 : 55"], and the input is lst.map(ratio_to_float, na_action = "ignore").

Comment: Oh.. In the above answer the input ratio is a string like `"37:63"`. So you want a list with the answers to those?

Comment: @GuoXianYau so what is `lst` that it has a `map` function that takes an `na_action` argument?

Comment: @JonClements It's actually Series from pandas library.

Comment: @AniMenon Essentially.

Comment: @GuoXianYau might be worth editing your question to include that then - it completely changes the context

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do this by making a List.
**Tha main reason to use a list, you can take many floating number and getting a result by iteration.**
remove `space` from `ratio.split(" : ")` to `ratio.split(":")`

```
def ratio_to_float(ratio):
    numer = ratio.split(":").list
    if int(numer[1]) == 0:
        num = math.inf
        print(num)
    else:
        num = int(numer[0])/int(numer[1])
        print(num)
    return num
```

Comment: This is same as the other two answers.

Comment: are you understand this answer? I used a list to store getting split value

Comment: No big difference.

Comment: @AniMenon: really? I want a question. Just think, If you have a list of number and need to getting every pair floating point number, so what can you do that? For Example: `10:5:4:2:6:3 .....`

Comment: And your script works that way? It would have been good for that use case but you code doesn't work like that!

Comment: @AniMenon: I think here is this platform, where a questioner want to get different type of  answer. that why you should answer by every possibilities. It's my own opinion. Sometimes I ask a portion of big question for better understand in SO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115783/discussion-between-ani-menon-and-sakib-ahammed).

Comment: @AniMenon: I am missing to write this. `ratio.split(":").list` thanks